# Identical Code on GPU and CPU but the results are different

Tags: floating-point, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I have implemented a BVH Traversal method on the gpu and on the cpu. The codes are identical and can be found here:

GPU CODE:

```
bool insideCell(const __global UnstructDataset* dataset, const int cellIndex, const float4 point)
{

  if(!inside(dataset->cell_box[cellIndex], point)) return false;

  if (dataset->cell_point[dataset->cell_points_beg_index[cellIndex]] == 4)
  {
    float barycoords[4];
    float4 cellpoints[4] = {
      dataset->point[dataset->cell_point[dataset->cell_points_beg_index[cellIndex] + 1]],
      dataset->point[dataset->cell_point[dataset->cell_points_beg_index[cellIndex] + 2]],
      dataset->point[dataset->cell_point[dataset->cell_points_beg_index[cellIndex] + 3]],
      dataset->point[dataset->cell_point[dataset->cell_points_beg_index[cellIndex] + 4]]
    };

    const float4 v1v0 = cellpoints[1] - cellpoints[0];
    const float4 v2v0 = cellpoints[2] - cellpoints[0];
    const float4 v3v2 = cellpoints[3] - cellpoints[2];
    const float4 pv0 = point - cellpoints[0];

    float tetvolumeinv = 1.0f / dot(v2v0, cross(v1v0, v3v2));

    // calculate the barycentric coordinates
    barycoords[0] = dot(cellpoints[2] - point, cross(cellpoints[1] - point, v3v2)) * tetvolumeinv;
    barycoords[1] = dot(v2v0, cross(pv0, v3v2)) * tetvolumeinv;
    barycoords[2] = dot(pv0, cross(v1v0, cellpoints[3] - point)) * tetvolumeinv;
    barycoords[3] = 1.0f - barycoords[0] - barycoords[1] - barycoords[2];

    // compute barycentric interpolation
    return true;

  }
}

// Locates the grid element which the point is residing in it.
int locateBVHElemIdx(
  __global UnstructDataset* dataset,
  __global BVHTree* bvh,
  float4 point
  ) {

      uint cell_index = 0;
      int todoOffset = 0, nodeNum = 0;
      int todo[64];

      while(true){

      // if the current node is an interior node
      if(nodeNum >= 0){
        const __global LinearBVHInteriorNode* node = &bvh->interior_nodes[nodeNum];
        const bool insideLeftChild   = inside(node->left_bound, point/*, node->splitAxis*/);
        const bool insideRightChilld = inside(node->right_bound, point/*, node->splitAxis*/);

        if(insideLeftChild && insideRightChilld){
          todo[todoOffset++] = node->children[1];
          nodeNum = node->children[0];

        } else if(insideLeftChild && !insideRightChilld){
          nodeNum = node->children[0];
        } else if(insideRightChilld && !insideLeftChild){
          nodeNum = node->children[1];
        } else {
          if(todoOffset == 0) break;
          nodeNum = todo[--todoOffset];
        }

      } else {

        const __global LinearBVHLeafNode* node = &bvh->leaf_nodes[-nodeNum - 1];

        // return node->lowIdx;

        // inside leaf node 
        for(int i = node->lowIdx; i < node->highIdx; i++){
          if(insideCell(dataset, i, point))
            return i;
        }

        if(todoOffset == 0) break;
        nodeNum = todo[--todoOffset];

      }     

    }

  return 0;
}
```

CPU CODE:

```
bool UnstructDataset::insideCell(PrimitiveIndex cellIndex, const glm::vec3& point) const {

  if (!m_cellBoxes[cellIndex].contains((float*)&point))
    return false;

    if (m_cellPoints[m_cellPointsBegIndices[cellIndex]] == 4)
  {
    float barycoords[4];
    glm::vec3 cellpoints[4] = {
        m_points[m_cellPoints[m_cellPointsBegIndices[cellIndex] + 1]],
        m_points[m_cellPoints[m_cellPointsBegIndices[cellIndex] + 2]],
        m_points[m_cellPoints[m_cellPointsBegIndices[cellIndex] + 3]],
        m_points[m_cellPoints[m_cellPointsBegIndices[cellIndex] + 4]]
    };

    const glm::vec3 v1v0 = cellpoints[1] - cellpoints[0];
    const glm::vec3 v2v0 = cellpoints[2] - cellpoints[0];
    const glm::vec3 v3v2 = cellpoints[3] - cellpoints[2];
    const glm::vec3 pv0 = point - cellpoints[0];

    float tetvolumeinv = 1.0f / glm::dot(v2v0, glm::cross(v1v0, v3v2));

    // calculate the barycentric coordinates
    barycoords[0] = glm::dot(cellpoints[2] - point, glm::cross(cellpoints[1] - point, v3v2)) * tetvolumeinv;
    barycoords[1] = glm::dot(v2v0, glm::cross(pv0, v3v2)) * tetvolumeinv;
    barycoords[2] = glm::dot(pv0, glm::cross(v1v0, cellpoints[3] - point)) * tetvolumeinv;
    barycoords[3] = 1.0f - barycoords[0] - barycoords[1] - barycoords[2];

    // if the point is in the tetrahedron
    if (barycoords[0] < 0.0f || barycoords[1] < 0.0f || barycoords[2] < 0.0f || barycoords[3] < 0.0f)
        return false;

        return true;

  }
}

bool BVHTree::getBoundingPrimitiveIndex(const UnstructDataset* const datasetPtr, const float point[3], PrimitiveIndex& cell_index) {

    uint32_t idx = 0;
    int todoOffset = 0, nodeNum = 0;
    int todo[64];

    while(true){

    // if the current node is an interior node
    if(nodeNum >= 0){

      const LinearBVHInteriorNode* node = &m_interior_nodes[nodeNum];

      const bool insideLeftChild   = node->leftBound.contains(point/*, node->splitAxis*/);
      const bool insideRightChilld = node->rightBound.contains(point/*, node->splitAxis*/);

      if(insideLeftChild && insideRightChilld){
        todo[todoOffset++] = node->children[1];
        nodeNum = node->children[0];

      } else if(insideLeftChild && !insideRightChilld){
        nodeNum = node->children[0];
      } else if(insideRightChilld && !insideLeftChild){
        nodeNum = node->children[1];
      } else {
        if(todoOffset == 0) break;
        nodeNum = todo[--todoOffset];
      }

    } else {

      const LinearBVHLeafNode* node = &m_leaf_nodes[-nodeNum - 1];

      // inside leaf node 
      for(int i = node->lowIdx; i < node->highIdx; i++){
                if( datasetPtr->insideCell( i, glm::vec3( point[0], point[1], point[2] ) ) ){
          cell_index = i;

          return true;
                }
      }

      if(todoOffset == 0) break;
            nodeNum = todo[--todoOffset];

    }
  }

    return false;
}
```

The problem is when I use the code, I will get very close nodes of the BVH. To me, it seems the floating point operations on gpu and cpu are not identical and this cause the algorithm results in different nodes while both codes are working correct. Can it be the case?

Comment: Your GPU code doesn't seem to use the barycentric coordinates to check if the point is inside the tetrahedron, like the CPU code does.

Comment: @jprice you are right! Sorry about that! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jprice mentioned in the comments, there was bug in the code. So, I was not checking barycentric coords to be between 0.0 and 1.0 to see if the point is actually in the cell or not. After fixing the bug, both results are identical.